# Create a "fake" file to pass in to Crystal Report API

Tags: crystal-reports, makefile, memorystream

Attempting to create a PDF from a Crystal Report file in C# using the Crystal Report API (version 13) - The API requires that the Crystal Report file be passed in as a file. I currently have the report as a memory stream and would prefer to not save it to a file, use it, then delete the file when done.

Is there any way to "fake" sending a file without creating an actual file? (Parameter it requires is a filename.)

This application runs on a server in the cloud and will have multiple instances and other things that make me not want to try to deal with permissions and file structure and things like that that may crop up when creating a "real" file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. If it's expecting a filename as a parameter, it's using OpenFile() or the equivalent to open a physical file on disk. How do you fake it?

Every OS I've ever worked with has a mechanism for getting a temporary filename; in .NET, you can use [System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) for exactly this sort of purpose.

Comment: Thanks! The GetTempFileName option had not crossed my mind. Thank you for taking the time to answer what must seem like a dumb question!

Comment: @Mark, no problem. Welcome to StackOverflow - this is what makes it a useful place to spend your time on. :)